# thread1: exc_bad_instruction on swift

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-instruction

I do have error Thread1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION. Been trying very hard on this. Any helpful personnel out there?

import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class PlaySoundsViewController: UIViewController {

```
var filePathUrl: NSURL!
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
var receivedAudio:RecordedAudio!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    audioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: receivedAudio.filePathUrl)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func playFastAudio(sender: UIButton) {
    audioPlayer!.stop()
    audioPlayer!.rate = 1.5
    audioPlayer!.currentTime = 0.0
    audioPlayer!.play()
}

@IBAction func playSlowAudio(sender: UIButton) {
    // play audio slow
    audioPlayer!.stop()
    audioPlayer!.rate = 0.5
    audioPlayer!.currentTime = 0.0
    audioPlayer!.play()


}
@IBAction func StopButtonSound(sender: UIButton) {
    audioPlayer!.stop()
}
```

}

Comment: I can't see that receivedAudio and relatively receivedAudio.filePathUrl is defined somewhere but you are using it in viewDidLoad to create AV object.

Comment: Ah, likely passing via segue. What is the error line then?

Comment: I am sorry for the misleading question. However, 
audioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: receivedAudio.filePathUrl)
fails me at runtime.

Comment: Are you passing the receivedAudio via segue from the parent view controller? Are you sure it is being passed actually?